# Application Insights - How to sort by custom dimension

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I would like to sort the results of my query according to `customDimension.MyCustomProperty` which is present in all entities and is a number. How can I do that?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

What I would suggest is first `extend`ing your result set with your customDimension. Then you'll have to cast your new column to either a string, an int or a double. The reason for this is that `customDimensions` is considered a dynamic column

A quick example:

```
traces
| extend sortKey = toint(customDimensions.MyCustomProperty)
| order by sortKey asc
```

The casting options are:

- tostring()
- toint()
- todouble()

If you want to remove the sorting key after the actual sort, you can `project-away` the new column.

Comment: note: you only need to use that `['blah']` syntax if your custom dimension (or measurement) contains special characters.  otherwise you can just do `customDimensions.MyCustomProperty`.  also, *generally* if the value is numeric, you should put it in customMeasurements instead, customDimensions are treated as strings by processing

Comment: @JohnGardner Fair enough, I'll edit the usage of [''...] out. I also did not know about customMeasurements vs customDimensions. You've given me some reading up to do, so thanks for that :)

Comment: Why arent any of my custom properties in customDimensions when logging to appInsights?